# Can't move TextFlow inside a new scene

Tags: java, scala, javafx, scalafx

In my ScalaFX project I want to create a separate help page for the user in which he/she can click a topic which causes instructions to appear next to the clickable topics.

Problem is that when I create the new scene for the help page no matter what I do I can't move the `TextFlow` around. It stays in the same place in top of the `ListView`. See picture for reference.

```
 helpMenu.onAction = (ae: ActionEvent) => {
    val helpStage = new Stage()
    helpStage.setTitle("A wild help stage appears!")
    val helpScene = new Scene(scene.width.get * 0.6, scene.height.get * 0.8) {
      val listView        = new ListView(List.tabulate(3) { n => "Option " + (n + 1) })
      val text1           = new Text("This is fine\n*zips coffee*\nThis is all fine.")
      val textFlow        = new TextFlow(text1)
      /*
       * Nothing below changes where the text appears in the new scene.
       */
      textFlow.layoutX  <== listView.width.get
      textFlow.alignmentInParent_=(Pos.TOP_RIGHT)
      textFlow.alignmentInParent_=(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER)
      text1.alignmentInParent_=(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER)

      listView.prefHeight <== scene.height.get * 0.4
      content.addAll(listView, textFlow)

    }
    helpStage.setScene(helpScene)
    helpStage.show()
    helpScene.listView.onMouseClicked = (le: MouseEvent) => {
      val item = helpScene.listView.selectionModel.apply.getSelectedItem
    }
  }
```

What I want to know is how can I orient text next to the list view? The goal is to make the instructions to appear there. My plan was to use

`helpScene.listView.onMouseClicked = (le: MouseEvent) => {
      val item = helpScene.listView.selectionModel.apply.getSelectedItem
    }`

to this purpose since we can easily determine what was clicked inside the list.

[image]

Comment: Hi Sampo. Did the code I provided address your problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: @MikeAllen Hi Mike. I haven't had the time to look into your answer due to other school work. I'll try my best to check it during this week.

Comment: No worries. Keep me posted... ;-)

Comment: @MikeAllen Thank you! The guide and your example code was exactly, and I mean *exactly*, what I needed! And the general idea is that user can click an option, which is a named topic, and appropriate help text appears on the left side of the screen. Again, big thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you need to add the `ListView` and `TextFlow` elements to a container that will control how they are laid out. In the code below, I'm using an `HBox` for that purpose, which puts the two side-by-side. (There are other options in the `scalafx.scene.layout` package, such as `VBox`, `BorderPane`, etc. [This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/jfxpub-layout.htm), for the older *JavaFX* 2 release, might help give you a better appreciation of the topic.)

After that, I'm a little unclear what you're trying to achieve, but what I think you're trying to do is to show different text in the `TextFlow` depending upon which item in the `ListView` is selected. If that's the case, then the following example addresses that by using a change of selection to trigger a change in TextFlow content. (If this isn't what you had in mind, can you elaborate on your requirements?)

Also, I've simplified some of your code to use *ScalaFX*'s properties (as opposed to *JavaFX*'s *getters & setters*).

```scala
onAction = (ae: ActionEvent) =>  {
  val helpStage = new Stage() {

    // Make room for the list view and the text flow.
    width = 400

    // Set the help text to the default.
    val defaultText = "Please make\na selection"
    val helpText = new Text(defaultText)

    // Help for each option in the list view. If a key doesn't match, then the default
    // text is displayed.
    val optionText = Map(
      "Option 1" -> "This is\nsome help for\nOption 1",
      "Option 2" -> "And this is\nsome help for\nOption 2",
      "Option 3" -> "Finally, this is\nsome help for\nOption 3",
    ).withDefaultValue(defaultText)

    // Title the stage and set the scene...
    title = "A wild help stage appears!"
    scene = new Scene {

      val listView = new ListView(List.tabulate(3) { n => "Option " + (n + 1) }) {

        // Change the help text when the selection changes.
        selectionModel().selectedItem.onChange {(_, _, selected) =>
          helpText.text = optionText(selected);
        }
      }

      // Add the help text to the text flow.
      val textFlow = new TextFlow(helpText)

      // Put list view and text flow elements side-by-side.
      content = new HBox(listView, textFlow)
    }
  }
  helpStage.show()
}
```